# DateTextBox validation is not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, dojo

I want to validate the DateTextBox field when the user enter invalid input like "abcd".If the user enters the invalid input i wanna the restrict the form submission.

Below is the code i m using for validation.But whenever i gave the 'fromdate' and 'todate' click the button form is validated properly and submission restricted.But in the 'fromdate' calender popup all the dates are striked out.i wanna to reset the constraints.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

```
 function validateForm()
{   alert('Validate');
    var form = dijit.byId("form1");
    alert('form '+form);
    if(form.validate()) {   
        console.info("It was valid!");
    } else {
    var result= alert('The value entered is invalid.Please provide the valid input.');
    if(result= true){

    //
   }


<tr>
            <td class="label"><label
                title="A single Deduction Date can be entered in the From/To fields or a range of Deduction Dates can be entered to search multiple days.">
            Deduction Date From</label></td>
            <td class="content"><form:input
                path="deductionSearchFilter.deductionDateFrom" size='20'
                id="fromDedDate" dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
                onchange="dijit.byId('toDedDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];"
                size="10" style="width: 114"
                title="A single Deduction Date can be entered in the From/To fields or a range of Deduction Dates can be entered to search multiple days." />
            <span class="required">To </span><form:input
                path="deductionSearchFilter.deductionDateTo" id="toDedDate"
                dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
                onchange="dijit.byId('fromDedDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];"
                size="10" style="width: 114"
                title="A single Deduction
          Date can be entered in the From/To fields or a range of Deduction Dates can be entered to search multiple days." />

            </td>
        </tr>


<td align='center'><input id="search" onclick="validateForm();" type="submit" name="Search"
                value="Search" class="button"
                title="View the results of search" />
            </td>
```

Comment: 1) You used wrong tags. You are looking for javascript and not java  (jsp)
2) Do you use any particular javascript framework in your project? The answwer really depends on this information.

Comment: Sorry for appearing late. Would this be solution for you? http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html

Comment: `if(result= true)` Are you sure you didn't mean `===`